# How to scroll multiple textViews simultaneously in Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, textview

I have not found an answer to this for Swift and XCode, so:

I have a lot of data going into multiple textViews. 100 lines to be exact. The screen has a horizontal scrollView to scroll between the various textView columns. All of the textViews have independent scrolling within themselves but it's weird to scroll each individually since the user will need to compare the data at each row position simultaneously.

How in the hell can I scroll all the textViews at once?
I have considered the option of using labels instead of textViews and have vertical and horizontal scrolling but I much prefer the textView columns.

Also I'm a complete beginner so talk to me like one :)
Because I'm a beginner I do as much as possible in UI Builder as opposed to programatically...

Screenshot of the Views
[image]

Not much code to be seen really:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var downFour: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var downThree: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var downTwo: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var downOne: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var evenZero: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var plueOne: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusTwo: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusThree: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusFour: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// Calculate button tapped will cause math to occur and the text field to show the values
// Resets all textViews before calculation
@IBAction func calculateCoursing(_ sender: UIButton) {
    downFour.text = ""
    downThree.text = ""
    downTwo.text = ""
    downOne.text = ""
    evenZero.text = ""
    plusOne.text = ""
    plusTwo.text = ""
    plusThree.text = ""
    plusFour.text = ""
    calculateCoursing()
    
}
// Acts to dismiss number keyboard when user taps outside
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    brickHeight.resignFirstResponder()
}

func calculateCoursing() {
        for index in 1...100 {
            downFour.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 33)\n"
            downThree.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 45)\n"
            downTwo.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 53)\n"
            downOne.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 65)\n"
            evenZero.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 73)\n"
            plusOne.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 85)\n"
            plusTwo.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 93)\n"
            plusThree.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 105)\n"
            plusFour.text! += "Unit \(index) = \(index * 113)\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I decided to change my whole program to use labels with a dynamic scroll view instead. However I've seen this question asked many times and I really think this would be a very valuable technique to know :)